# Track User's Device Type - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, web, coldfusion-9

I am sending out a daily survey email and I want to track the device types (mobile, tablet, pc, etc.) my users are accessing it from. I need to save these information to allow me some sort of analysis at a later point (ex. How many accessed the survey from their phone and did not complete it (I am already tracking who is starting the survey and when)). This level of information will potentially help me develop a better application that would be mobile friendly.

Is it possible to gather these type of data and then store it in a database table?

I am using ColdFusion 9 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You want to look at the user agent string in the requests that the browser or mail client make to you when loading images or pages. Traditionally, you'd embed a 1x1 pixel tracking image in you mail, where the image url is tracker.cfm?user=#your user ID here#

In the request, you get the user ID in the URL and the user agent in CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT, which you can then store and process later.

Almost the harder part of the exercise is making sense of the data you get. User agent strings aren't that nice to parse, and may be withheld in certain circumstances. Have you looked at using Google Analytics for the web-side of your tracking? That (or something like it) will do a good job of making sense of the data and is very easy to implement.

Comment: Embedding images in email like that is called a "webbug" and they are routinely blocked. I wouldn't rely on that.

Comment: What @AlEverett is saying is that many users block all images by default in their email. The tracking image works...but only if it's loaded. Just make sure to coach whoever is looking at the data that it's only partially accurate because of this.

Comment: thanks guys. Still working on that. I will post an answer as soon as i am done.

Comment: i created cases with `findnocase` and i am checking the incoming string for keywords such us 'chrome', and 'firefox' and im saving the output in a db table. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

You could use CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT and then try to parse out the actual devices.  We had a similar need and found that google analytics fit our need because it can tell you all of the info you are looking for without much work on your part

Answer (score 0):

I also find this site very helpful in accomplishing this sort of task. It works with most languages as well, [mobile browser detection](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)